# Microphone not working HP Pavilion dv6500

Tags: microphone, hp-pavilion

Input shows up as internal microphone in the Sound separator in System Settings, but the recording doesn't work at all (no sound) and the input level bar is almost full. I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
I have installed and updated pavucontrol but I have no idea what do to next.
Any suggestions on what I should do?
[image]
[image]

When I type the command $ gstreamer-properties says *no command found*.
When I run alsamixer what shows up is the following.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The microphone is detected and working therefore the problem is in the software you're using to record that most likely has some other input selected.

Comment: Ok. What should I do then?

Comment: Check the input selected in the software you didn't bother to mention?

Comment: I... don't know how to check it beyond the print screen I've posted in here. Can you help me?